# Gender illusions?

Tags: género, neutralidad-de-género, rae, formas-irregulares, dle

This is a multiple question about genders.

Recently I just wondered about this subject while writing and thought:

Why is *juez* or *concejal* considered masculine while *agente* and *detective* are not?

Why aren't *ciclista* and *dentista* feminine but *modista* is?

The DRAE accepts the gender distinctive even when it is not useful, so **dentisto** and **modisto** are accepted (haha it's so ridiculous it makes me laugh).

For instance this is correct:

> Mi modisto arregló mi vestido mientras fui a mi dentisto.

Why?

Comment: Are you asking why some nouns that end with "o" are feminine, while some nouns that end with "a" are masculine?

Comment: Yes that's what I am asking. And why is dentisto accepted and detective or agente considered masculine too.

Comment: "La palabra dentisto no está en el diccionario" from RAE, are you sure is accepted?

Comment: Yes it is just a formation, there are many words that are not in the dictionary but are accepted. Here is the link for the rules from RAE that say it doesn't matter so modisto is viable for example. [Section 3, paragraph b](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=g%E9nero2) For example "las poetas" would be accepted too.

Comment: @Joze Femenine words are present in RAE dictionary, e.g. look for "concejal" and "concejala": they lead to "concejal, la.", but if you look for "dentisto" it says the word doesn't exist. I have never heard of it, and it sounds terrible to me (but modisto is OK). Not all names can have a distint word for femenine gender: the most famous case is "miembro" (A Spanish minister used "miembra" and was widely critized because it wasn't correct") Ngram Viewer gives no use of "dentisto": http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dentisto%2Cdentista&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=10&smoothing=3

Comment: En el mismo sitio que indicas se puede ver que "modisto" es un caso excepcional. No hay nada que haga pensar que se admita dentisto, ciclisto o pesimisto. Tú puedes usar "dentisto" al igual que puedes usar "pitufar", pero será incorrecto.

Comment: Could you please provide some reference about *dentisto* being an accepted Spanish word? I ask you because in numeral 3, literal b) of the entry for [género](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=g%E9nero2) (*Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*), *modisto* is mentioned as the only exception for professions ending with an *a*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why aren't *ciclista* and *dentista* feminine but *modista* is?

Dentisto no es correcto en ningún caso, al igual que tampoco lo son electricisto, periodisto, pesimisto, populisto, sociolisto, catolicisto ni ciclisto.

El [sufijo -ista](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?TIPO_HTML=2&TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=ista) se aplica para ambos géneros. La palabra "modisto" es un caso excepcional donde su uso intensivo incorrecto se popularizó de tal forma que se acabó aceptando, pero solo es una excepción.

> The DRAE accepts the gender distinctive even when it is not useful, so
>   dentisto and modisto are accepted (haha it's so ridiculous it makes me
>   laugh).
>
> For instance this is correct:
>
> ```
> Mi modisto arregló mi vestido mientras fui a mi dentisto.
> ```
>
> Why?

Creo que estás equivocado. Tal vez en algún sitio se diga "dentisto", no te lo puedo negar, pero decir "dentisto" es incorrecto. Es una incorrección (que será de uso habitual en ciertos sitios) pero es como cuando yo cometo laísmo o leísmo.

Que un grupo de personas cometamos laísmo no significa que se permita el laísmo. Que un grupo de personas digan "dentisto" no significa que se permita dicha atrocidad.

Comment: Tienes razón, precisamente esa es la razón por la que hice esta pregunta. Porque dentisto no suena ni más remotamente correcto. Pero entonces ¿porqué modista es una excepción? Pienso es evidente que electricisto y tus otros ejemplos no sean correctos, aunque ya he visto dentisto por más ridículo que suene. (1 o 2 veces) Esperemos otras respuestas a ver si alguien tiene una percepción diferente sobre el tema...

Comment: Mi OPINIÓN es que hace unas pocas décadas un grupo de snob (con dinero pero sin cultura) empezaron a usar incorrectamente esa palabra en sus selectos ambientes de la alta costura. Y con el tiempo su uso se acabó extendiendo entre los seguidores de la moda.

Comment: @Joze, Nexus is absolutely right. Dentisto is such an epic wrong that its epicness alone could make it sound right.

Comment: @Nexus ur rep is 666!!! EPIC haha. I agree its an epic wrong!! That's why I ask!! :-)